# Formating a number to two decimals without rounding up and converting to Double

Tags: java, input, string-formatting

I know this has been questioned alot of times but i tried all solutions in other threads and i cant find one that matches what i want ...

So i have one input something like this `-9.22841` which is read as a String, what i want to do is to format this number to two decimals like this `-9.23` without rounding it up and then converting it to double without losing this format...

I have tried many ways like `String.format("%.2f",number)` and the one below ...

```
  String l = -9.22841
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,00");
  String tmp =df.format(l);
  double t = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
```

and this one:

```
  String l = -9.22841
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
  String tmp =df.format(l);
  double t = Double.parseDouble(tmp);
```

but everytime i try to convert to double in the `String.format("%.2f",number)` or `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");` gives error converting to double

and when i do this :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,00");
```

The output is wrong and is something like this `-9.23` where it should be `-9.22`

Thanks for your time ...

Comment: How, precisely, are you attempting to "convert to double"?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using any formats with commas...

Comment: (I'm also having trouble working out exactly whether the aim is to parse, format, or parse twice... it would help if you'd restrict your question to *one* operation, e.g. formatting from `double` to `String`, with sample inputs and expected outputs.)

Comment: Do note that standard printf-style formatting will always round, and -9.228 will always round to -9.23.  If you don't want rounding, multiply times 100, cast to int, cast back to float, and divide by 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just chop off the String two spaces after the decimal:

```
String number = "-9.22841";
String shorterNumber = number.substring(0, number.indexOf(".")+3);
double t = Double.parseDouble(shorterNumber);
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Good point -you can take the max of length of the substring vs 3.

Answer (score 2):

Thats what you want:

```
String number = "-9.22841";
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00"); 
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN); 
number = formatter.format(Double.valueOf(number));
System.out.println(number);
```

The output will be:

-9,22

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow function:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.RoundingMode;


public static double formatValue(Double number) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00");

        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        return Double.parseDouble(df.format(number));
    }
```

**Input = 31.6227890 ,
OutPUT = 31.62**

Answer (score 0):

For someone looking full decimal handling:Kotlin

```
fun validateNumber(number: String): String {
        return if (number.contains(".") && number.length > 3+number.indexOf("."))
            number.substring(0, number.indexOf(".")+3)
        else if (number.contains(".")){
            number.substring(0, number.indexOf(".")+2)+"0"
        }else{
            "$number.00"
        }
    }
```